# Haproxy MQTT Connection limiting at just 30,000 connections per mqtt node

Tags: mqtt, load-balancing, haproxy, mqtt-vernemq, emqx

I am using haproxy to loadbalance my MQTT brokers cluster. Each MQTT Broker can handle up to 1,00,000 Connections easily. But the problem i am facing with haproxy is that is only handling upto30k connections per node. Whenever if any node is reaching near 32k connections, the haproxy CPU Would suddenly spike to 100% and now all connections start dropping.

The problem with this is, that for every 30k connection, i have to roll another MQTT broker. How can I increase it to at least 60k connections per MQTT broker node?

My Virtual Machine: 1 Cpu, 2 GB Ram. I have tried increasing CPU counts, and faced the same problem.

My config –

```
bind 0.0.0.0:1883
maxconn 1000000
mode tcp

#sticky session load balancing – new feature

stick-table type string len 32 size 200k expire 30m
stick on req.payload(0,0),mqtt_field_value(connect,client_identifier)
option clitcpka # For TCP keep-alive
option tcplog

timeout client 600s
timeout server 2h
timeout check 5000

server mqtt1 10.20.236.140:1883 check-send-proxy send-proxy-v2 check inter 10s fall 2 rise 5
server mqtt2 10.20.236.142:1883 check-send-proxy send-proxy-v2 check inter 10s fall 2 rise 5
server mqtt3 10.20.236.143:1883 check-send-proxy send-proxy-v2 check inter 10s fall 2 rise 5
```

I have also tuned system params

```
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=60000
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=16384
sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=16384

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range='1024 65535'

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='1024 4096 16777216'
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='1024 4096 16777216'

modprobe ip_conntrack
sysctl -w net.nf_conntrack_max=1000000
sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=1000000
sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait=30
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets=1048576
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=15

tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf << EOF
root      soft   nofile      1048576
root      hard   nofile      1048576
haproxy    soft   nproc      1048576
haproxy    hard   nproc      1048576
EOF
```

Output of Haproxy `haproxy -v`

```
HAProxy version 2.4.18-1ppa1~focal 2022/07/27 - https://haproxy.org/
Status: long-term supported branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q2 2026.
Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-2.4.18.html
Running on: Linux 5.4.0-122-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 22 15:00:31 UTC 2022 x86_64
Build options :
  TARGET  = linux-glibc
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = cc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/haproxy-96Se88/haproxy-2.4.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fwrapv -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unused-label -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-clobbered -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-cast-function-type -Wtype-limits -Wshift-negative-value -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference
  OPTIONS = USE_PCRE2=1 USE_PCRE2_JIT=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_SLZ=1 USE_SYSTEMD=1 USE_PROMEX=1
  DEBUG   = 

Feature list : +EPOLL -KQUEUE +NETFILTER -PCRE -PCRE_JIT +PCRE2 +PCRE2_JIT +POLL -PRIVATE_CACHE +THREAD -PTHREAD_PSHARED +BACKTRACE -STATIC_PCRE -STATIC_PCRE2 +TPROXY +LINUX_TPROXY +LINUX_SPLICE +LIBCRYPT +CRYPT_H +GETADDRINFO +OPENSSL +LUA +FUTEX +ACCEPT4 -CLOSEFROM -ZLIB +SLZ +CPU_AFFINITY +TFO +NS +DL +RT -DEVICEATLAS -51DEGREES -WURFL +SYSTEMD -OBSOLETE_LINKER +PRCTL -PROCCTL +THREAD_DUMP -EVPORTS -OT -QUIC +PROMEX -MEMORY_PROFILING

Default settings :
  bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

Built with multi-threading support (MAX_THREADS=64, default=1).
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports : TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
Built with Lua version : Lua 5.3.3
Built with the Prometheus exporter as a service
Built with network namespace support.
Built with libslz for stateless compression.
Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND
Built with PCRE2 version : 10.34 2019-11-21
PCRE2 library supports JIT : yes
Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with gcc compiler version 9.4.0

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.

Available multiplexer protocols :
(protocols marked as <default> cannot be specified using 'proto' keyword)
              h2 : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H2       flags=HTX|CLEAN_ABRT|HOL_RISK|NO_UPG
            fcgi : mode=HTTP       side=BE        mux=FCGI     flags=HTX|HOL_RISK|NO_UPG
       <default> : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H1       flags=HTX
              h1 : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H1       flags=HTX|NO_UPG
       <default> : mode=TCP        side=FE|BE     mux=PASS     flags=
            none : mode=TCP        side=FE|BE     mux=PASS     flags=NO_UPG

Available services : prometheus-exporter
Available filters :
        [SPOE] spoe
        [CACHE] cache
        [FCGI] fcgi-app
        [COMP] compression
        [TRACE] trace
```

Comment: Please also mention the size of the machine you're using for haproxy.

Comment: please add the output of `haproxy -vv` to the description.

Comment: I added more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your config that should account for why you can't achieve more than 30K connections without the CPU spiking. I am not sure those tuned system parameters are doing you any good.

For reference, I am successfully running HAProxy (vanilla docker image `haproxy:2.4.17`) with 2 CPU and 4G memory and can reach my `maxconn` of 150K without pegging the CPU.)

Outside of the per instance scaling problem you are having, it looks like another problem you may have is you are assuming 1 HAProxy to 1 MQTT broker.

> The problem with this is, that for every 30k connection, i have to roll another MQTT broker.

In my experience it is better to run multiple HAProxy nodes in front of a single broker. (Not sure what your constraints are here.) Having more than one instance of HAProxy per backend is critical. When you lose an instance, you will only lose a fraction of your traffic. (When, not if.) This is the critical piece here, because when the traffic gets dropped the clients will all try to re-connect at the same time. That is how you accidentally DDoS yourself because of a lost virtual machine or pod.

At your current vertical scale (CPU and memory) you can get to 30K connections. That would be 34 nodes if you set `maxconn` 30K. That should be easily doable if you run them as Kubernetes pods as a deployment with something like ELB in front of your HAProxy cluster. One way or another, you need to figure out how to run HAProxy as a cluster without duplicating your backends.

A good rule of thumb is "scale out when scaling up no longer works".